# Why does -10//3 give -4?

Tags: python

Why does -10//3 give -4
I thought the // operator just acts as a divide but discards the remainder.
I am using python 3.4.2 IDLE

This also seems to be happening for the % operator as well
ie. -10 % 3 gives 2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python always rounds to negative infinite for integer division and remainder operations.

Why Python was designed that way is explained by Python's creator [here](http://python-history.blogspot.nl/2010/08/why-pythons-integer-division-floors.html).

Comment: @DavidYu If my answer solved your problem you can mark it as such by clicking the checkmark next to my answer. Doing so will give both me and you a little reputation.